# Infinitely Scrolling Div With Wraparound Using CSS3 Animations

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

I have created an animated scrolling `<div>` that is semi-working. The animation works except for the fact that I would like it to "wrap around." By that I mean that as the first element leaves the bottom of the screen it comes down from the top, or stacks on top of a "queue" at the top.

How can I accomplish this? Would using 2 identical divs be the only way?

My CSS code is as follows:

```
.posts 
{
-webkit-animation: movetweets 10s linear infinite;
-moz-animation: movetweets 10s linear infinite;
-o-animation: movetweets 10s linear infinite;
}   

@-webkit-keyframes movetweets {
    from {margin-top: -100%;}
    to {margin-top: 100%;}
}
@-moz-keyframes movetweets {
    from {margin-top: -100%;}
    to {margin-top: 100%;}
}
@-o-keyframes movetweets {
    from {margin-top: -100%;}
    to {margin-top: 100%;}
}
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jtholla2/q14ff1wx/7/) with some generic html that is the same format of my HTML.

Comment: Can you share your HTML? Basically you need to use Javascript to do this. Get the height of the window and track the position of the element that's scrolling. Once it goes below the visible area, set the position back to the top of the window.

Comment: You can see a JSFiddle [here.](http://jsfiddle.net/jtholla2/q14ff1wx/7/)

Comment: I'm trying to do the same thing and I'm wondering if you found a CSS solution?

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a no jquery/js solution, I've made the fiddle below that works in Chrome, Firefox, IE, and Safari. I've used the marquee tag in lieu of CSS3 animations because I feel it is a more elegant solution.

http://jsfiddle.net/simsketch/aj5t2m1k/

```html
<div style="width: 125px; height: text-align:left; box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px #C0C0C0; background: #FFFFFF; padding: 0px;">
  <marquee onmouseover='this.stop();' onmouseout='this.start();' direction="up" height="125" scrollamount="2">
    <div>
      <a href="#" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/125x125" width="125" height="125" alt="scrolling vertical image marquee" /> </a>
    </div>
    <div><br/>
      <a href="#" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/125x125" width="125" height="125" /></a>
    </div>
    <div><br/>
      <a href="#">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/125x125" width="125" height="125" /></a>
    </div>
    <div><br/>
      <a href="#" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/125x125" width="125" height="125" /></a>
    </div>
  </marquee>
</div>
```

If using jquery or js is acceptable, below is a great vertical slider with a bunch of options.

http://www.jssor.com/demos/vertical-slider.html

Comment: Your example with the marquee has the same problem that I was describing that my solution was having. As far as the js/jquery library it won't work for what I need. Thanks though!